# Как конвертировать данные с UNIX-timestamp в дату на React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, конвертация, unixtimestamp

Как поменять `droplet.date_of_birth`, если с сервера приходит UNIX-timestamp 777319075, а нужно 14.04.2015 к примеру.

```js
const TableBody = ({ droplets }) => {
    return (
        <>
            {droplets.map((droplet, index) =>
                <tr className={s.area} key={index}>
                    <td ><Checkbox /></td>
                    <td>{droplet.num}</td>
                    <td>{droplet.first_name}</td>
                    <td>{droplet.last_name}</td>
                    <td>{droplet.date_of_birth}</td>
                    <td>{droplet.height}</td>
                    <td>{droplet.weight}</td>
                    <td>{droplet.salary}</td>
                    <td><button type="submit" className={s.button}><Edit /></button></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" className={s.button}><Trash /></button></td>
                </tr>
            )
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вот так можно

```js
let a = 777319075 *1000
let d = new Date(a)
console.log(d.toDateString())
console.log(d.toISOString())
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString("ru-RU"))
```

У `Date` есть много методов, я привел всего три.

То есть в ваш код можно вставить это:

```js
let date_form = ts => new Date(ts).toDateString("ru-RU");
```

Comment: спасибо! но я так понимаю этим методом я могу достать одно значение даты и поменять его. Как добраться ко всем значениям date_of_birth в массиве map и вставить туда уже измененные данные. Вопрос возможно на начальном уровне JS но я только учусь, сори если не правильно сформулировал

Comment: насколько я понимаю у вас это перебор значений (не силен в этой лексике), так почему бы не вызывать функцию для каждого `{droplet.date_of_birth}`. Т. е. `ts` переменной передать `{droplet.date_of_birth}` и тут же вызвать функциюб прямо в тэгах `<td></td>`. Или вызвать функцию прямо на входе в перебор и переменную `date_form ` в тэгах `<td></td>`

Comment: Ну, вообще почитал про `React` чуть. И ваш кусок кода похож на `render()`. И на сколько я виже функции вызываются в конструкторе, а в `render()` уже передаются готовые данные без обработки.